# Did Kakeru stay, leave to travel abroad, or is there really no closure by design, at the end of Glasslip?

Tags: glasslip

Vague ending. What happened?

I am looking for credible, canon / official / source material / word of god sources. For this question, Wikia, wikipedia, reddit, myanimelist, boards or the like will be disregarded as pure speculation. DVD bonus material, showmakers' interviews, etc... is what I am really looking for.

What are the whereabouts of Kakeru as of the first day of school of the second semester shown at the ending of Glasslip?

Comment: shouldn't discount Wiki evidence, some of the good Wiki's have citation to Writer/Developer interviews or to Extra Works like Art/Material Books, especially how sometimes these things are in japanese and the wikis provide an English citation (ie. TYPE-MOON Wikia)

Comment: @Memor-X I spent one night browsing the very cites I choose to exclude. Only speculation. I think this is in the same line as other deliberately-left-open endings, but I want to see if someone can dig something official.

Answer (score -1):

I think he left because the tent is gone and i thought he went into his room not his tent after that touko heard kakeru called her name and they mentioned they want to meet each other so they can see the  same thing like calling each other name in the first and last episode